# Regarding TLS/SSL certificate associated with Razorpay API

Tags: ssl, certificate, razorpay

Please be informed that the TLS/SSL certificate associated with the Razorpay API will expire soon. We are scheduled to renew and import the new certificate on Jan 30th, 2024.

This is a yearly activity and doesn't require any action on your end if you haven't whitelisted/pinned our certificate. But if you have done so,please make sure you import and whitelist our new certificate on or before Jan 30th, 2024. You can download the new certificate from the link below:   and have action Button that goas to razor pay certification page to download certificates

razor pay send me this mail .what is this is it related for razor pay or my website? and what can i do?

Comment: *and what can i do?* Read it again.

Answer (score 2):

you can download the certificate from https://razorpay.com/docs/security/whitelists/ and paste it to the bottom of this file RazorPay/razorpay-php/libs/Requests-1.6.1/library/Requests/Transport/cacert.pem

Comment: i am using laravel in my project  ? i am not able to find the path which you mentioned

Comment: vendor/razorpay/razorpay/libs/Requests-2.0.4/certificates/cacert.pem. for laravel

Comment: no "/libs/Requests-2.0.4/certificates/" not exist in my vendor folder